# Rebuild weighted regression with optim in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, lm, weighted

I can successfully rebuild a linear regression in R using optim, but I get a wrong result when I also use a weight.

```
df <- mtcars
df$weight <- df$disp / mean(df$disp) #just an example
```

Here are the correct results using lm:

```
summary(lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = df))$r.squared
[1] 0.72618

summary(lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = df, weights = weight))$r.squared
[1] 0.6794141
```

Here the function and optim for the unweighted version that works:

```
minX.RSQ <- function(par) {
  esti <- par[1] + par[2]*df[,'cyl']
  resi <- (esti - df[,'mpg'])**2
  RSS <- sum(resi)
  SST <- sum((df[,'mpg'] - mean(df[,'mpg']))**2)
  -(1 - RSS / SST)
}
optim(par = c(0,0), minX.RSQ)$value
[1] -0.72618 #which is correct, cp. above
```

Here the function and optim for the weighted version, I tried weighted sums, but the result is NOT correct:

```
minW.RSQ <- function(par) {
  esti <- par[1] + par[2]*df[,'cyl']
  resi <- (esti - df[,'mpg'])**2 
  RSS <- sum(resi * df[,'weight'])
  SST <- sum((df[,'mpg'] - mean(df[,'mpg']))**2 * df[,'weight'])
  -(1 - RSS / SST)
}
optim(par = c(0,0), minW.RSQ)$value
[1] -0.7521823 #which is NOT correct, cp. above
```

How can I fix the function for the weighted version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are really close. You just need to use a weighted mean in your SST calc:

```r
minW.RSQ <- function(par) {
  esti <- par[1] + par[2]*df[,'cyl']
  resi <- (esti - df[,'mpg'])**2 
  RSS <- sum(resi * df[,'weight'])
  SST <- sum((df[,'mpg'] - weighted.mean(df[,'mpg'], w = df[,'weight']))**2 * df[,'weight'])
  -(1 - RSS / SST)
}
optim(par = c(0,0), minW.RSQ)$value
# [1] -0.6794141
```